# Create a facebook like error panel using Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-mobile

I want to be able to create a error panel like Facebook mobile app. It shows up whenever there is no internet connection. Anyone has any ideas on how to make such a panel using Jquery mobile. I want it to show some errors to the user.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: you should show what you have tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Facebook uses [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).
So it is only right to assume that they use event APIs from PhoneGap.

PhoneGap can handle events like on connect or on disconnect.

[PhoneGap Events Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events) |
[PhoneGap Online event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online) |
[PhoneGap Offline event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline)

To handle connections without PhoneGap.

You can loop an Ajax recursively to request again after each successful request.
What you can do is create an empty page at server.
and request that through ajax.
Then you can add a handler to ajax fail.

Since you are using jQuery, You can do

```
$.post(link)
.success(function(){
    //Still connected
})
.fail(function(){
    //Disconnected
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot Jomar. For me checking the error connection is working well. Infact right now we show a alert for that. I want to be able to slide a panel from top and display it with the same error. The thing I am struggling with is the creation of such a panel in Jquery mobile.

Comment: If you would like, you can create a custom bar at the top.
You can create it to fit the phone's screen if you use "position: fixed;" and add that element autoside of jquery-mobile's <div data-role="page"></div> This will prevent Jquerymobile from sliding it out with the transitions. When that div is fixed, and is outside any jquery mobile page then jquery mobile will not manipulate the div at least.
Also, make sure that it is still inside the `<body></body>` tags.

Comment: Also note that if you put the notification on another page, loading that external page through ajax will not load anything else outside the `<div data-role="page"></div>`

If my answer helped :) Please mark my answer as the answer by clicking the check beside my post.. thanks!

Comment: THanks alot Jomar. That was a great help. I will try it out and post the solution if I do get it right